# is that function must be constant under the following conditions

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-geometry

I'm talking about complex function

1. $f$ is analytic function on a region $D$ that include the point $z=0$.
2. for every $n\in N$ such $\frac{1}{n}$ is in $D$ , the function follows this condition $|f(\frac{1}{n})| \leq \dfrac{1}{2^n}$

is that function must be constant ?

Comment: You should modify 2: "for every $n\in\Bbb{N}$ **such that** $\frac{1}{n}$ **is in** $D$, $\left| f(\frac{1}{n}) \right| \leq \frac{1}{2^n}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it must be constant - indeed, that constant must be $0$, since clearly $f(0)=0$ by continuity. Hint for proof: if $f$ were not identically zero, then write $f(z)=z^kg(z)$ where $g$ is analytic and $g(z)\ne0$.

Comment: Thanks. hmm, I think I got it now.. because $|g(z)|$ should be 0 at z=0 because g analytic and condition 2. but g(z) != 0. is that the case ?

Answer (score 1):

Note that, since $f(0)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f\left(\frac1n\right)=0$, if $f$ is constant, then it can only be the null function.

If $f$ is *not* the null function, let $m$ be the smallest natural such that $f^{(m)}(0)\neq0$. Then, near $0$, you can write $f(z)$ as $a_mz^m+a_{m+1}z^{m+1}+\cdots$ and $a_m\neq0$. But then$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{f(1/n)}{1/n^m}=a_m\neq0.$$This is impossible, since$$\left\lvert\frac{f(1/n)}{1/n^m}\right\rvert\leqslant\frac{n^m}{2^n}$$and$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^m}{2^n}=0.$$